# Does it matter (speed and efficiency) if the same function calling appears multiple times in SQL query against SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Which is faster for the following 2 SQL queries? Does it slow the calculation if `SUM(Sales)` is used multiple times, or it will just be auto optimized?

SQL query #1:

```
SELECT 
    Category,
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(Sales) > 1000000 THEN SUM(Sales) / 1.3
        ELSE SUM(Sales)
    END AS Total
FROM 
    MyTable
GROUP BY 
    Category
```

SQL query #2:

```
SELECT 
    Category,
    CASE
        WHEN Sales > 1000000 THEN Sales / 1.3
        ELSE Sales
    END AS Total
FROM
    (SELECT 
         Category, SUM(Sales) AS Sales
     FROM 
         MyTable
     GROUP BY 
         Category) AS p
```

Comment: Why not test it and see?

Comment: Post the execution-plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: But before you post it, have a look at it and see if you can work it out. Running both queries in the same session will show the percentage of time spent on each.

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to use the exact same column-names for source and aggregate rows - you should rename `SUM(Sales) AS Sales` to `AS SalesSum` or similar, otherwise it's easy to get tripped-up.

Comment: the execution plans are the same, for the data(not a lot) I tested, there seems no difference. For the BI tools I use, there are a lot of function calls, using a lot nested queries makes it unpleasant to read. So I want to find out how many times the function is called in a SELECT query, both in SELECT & WHERE clause. I did some searching, but found noting instructive.

Comment: Did you try with `SUM(Sales)<1000000` because otherwise the `case` expression will short circuit. But otherwise you seem to have answered your own question.

Comment: @BrianHolsen Unfortunately you can't generalize from a simple example like the query you posted, that's because a SQL query bears very little resemblance to the actual operations the RDBMS will carry out: even a simple single edit to a query, such as adding a column to a `GROUP BY`, or using a `@tvv` to hold intermediate results instead of a CTE, can result in a drastically different outcome performance-wise.

Comment: Generally optimisers get this kind of stuff right, but query 2 is a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) solution that's easier to read, and you could convert to a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) for even better readability.

Comment: As per execution plan it seems both queries are same in sense of performance.

Comment: In general, in SQL, you're telling the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. If you have two different queries that are *logically* requesting the same result set, you should generally expect the optimizer to produce the same plan, no matter *how* you spelt out the requests.

Comment: And even across other languages, assuming they're not archaic, the age of optimizing code by trivial rearrangement is a thing of the past. Modern optimizers do a better job than most humans.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter at all. A query language like SQL is not an execution language, but only a language that you write the "form" of data you want to have in the result set, not how to obtain it.

The algebrizer and the optimizer will write a program call "execution plan" in which all operations (steps) will be executed. The query engine, will write an "operating" tree compound of many mathematical operations of the [relational algebrae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra)...

When you solve mathematical formulae you will first factor all expression that have the same content...

So the fact that you factor the "SUM(Sales)" has no importance at all. In good RDBMS this will be done systematically by the optimizer...

Comment: You might want to add that in SQL Server you can always compare the execution plan for both queries and most probably the execution plan for both of the above queries will be same.

Comment: In fact OP has already compared execution plans and seen they are the same.